# How to do bitwise operation in perl to get the count of longest sequence of 0s between two 1s

Tags: perl, bit

Given an integer I would like to print bit by bit in perl. For instance given a number 9, i would like to get

```
1
0
0
1
```

How do i achive this. Essentially what I am trying to do is, to get the number of longest 0s between two 1s. Meaning if the bitwise representation of a number is this
1000001001, I would like this perl function to return 5.

I would like to know whats the best way to code this in perl. Am totally new to perl.

Comment: What about `1001000`? 2 or 3?

Answer (score 4):

With leading zeroes:

```
my @bits = reverse unpack '(a)*', unpack 'B*', pack 'J>', $int;
```

Without:

```
my @bits = reverse unpack '(a)*', sprintf '%b', $int;
```

Notes:

- `reverse` is used to place the least significant bit in `$bits[0]`.
- `unpack '(a)*'` is used to split the string into individual bits.
- Both work with signed and unsigned integers.
- Both work with integers of the size (in bytes) given by `perl -V:ivsize`.

---

If you leave it as a string, you can take advantage of the regex engine to extract the sequences of zeroes.

```
use List::Util qw( max );
my $bin = sprintf '%b', $num;
my $longest = ( max map length, $bin =~ /1(0+)(?=1)/g ) || 0;
```

---

In C, you might do something like the following, but in Perl, it might be less efficient than the earlier solution:

```
my $longest = 0;
if ($num) {
   # Cast to unsigned so that >> inserts zeroes even for neg nums.
   $num = ~~$num;

   # Skip zeros not between 1s.
   $num >>= 1 while !($num & 1);

   while (1) {
      # Skip 1s.
      $num >>= 1 while $num & 1;

      last if !$num;

      # Count 0s.
      my $len = 0; ++$len, $num >>= 1 while !($num & 1);

      $longest = $len if $longest < $len;
   }
}
```